# Given m sets of n elements .Find the element which occurs in maximum number of sets in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, set

Given `m` sets of `n` integers that have `n` elements in them , find the element which occurs in maximum number of sets *Not maximum number of times*.

Here ,is the algorithm I implemented .

- scan the inputs one by one
- For each element the counter value is incremented . **this counter indicates the frequency of occurences in sets not within sets.** I hope I'm clear here
- Output the max element from count `max(count)`

```
 int main(){
   set <int> inner1;      //Here ,I have implemented just 2 sets 
   set <int> inner2;      
   set< set<int> > outer;      //a set of sets                 
   set< set<int> >:: iterator new_it;
   set<int >::iterator it;
  map <int ,int> count;  //the counter

   cout<<"enter the number of sets"<<endl;
   cin>>m;
   cout<<"enter the number of elements in each set"<<endl;
   cin>>n;
   for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
     int temp;
     inner1.insert(temp);
   }
   for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
     int temp;
     inner2.insert(temp);
   }
   outer.insert(inner1);       // a set of two sets .
   outer.insert(inner2);


  for (){
  for (){
    // THe MAIN CODE 
   
 }
```

My Question-

1. I want to implement it in such way that it can create `m sets in a set` with user input .
   I tried to implement it as of 2 sets for now ,but How can I implement it for `m` sets as
   per user's wish .

```
cout<<"enter the number of sets"<<endl;
cin>>m;
cout<<"enter the number of elements in each set"<<endl;
cin>>n;
```

I hope you get the gist

2. The algorithm for getting the element which occurs in maximum number of sets i.e. the main code

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can insert a set into set, so just loop over it the user input and do that. Iterate over this set of set and add into another map as element and no of sets this element is part of.

Comment: You don't need to store more than one set. After you've counted the elements of a set, that set is not interesting any more.

Comment: The premise, "m sets of n integers that have n elements in them", sounds pretty odd since as it says the same thing twice.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes..I think you're right because I had copy-pasted the question anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just write code as it is easy to understand:

```
unordered_map<int, int> global;

for(set<int> &s : sets){   //for each set you have
    for(int si : s) {      //for each element of the set (all unique by definition)
        global[si]++;
    }
}

int mostFrequent = *sets[0].begin();   //any existing element in any set is allowed
int frequency = global[mostFrequent];
for (auto& it: global) {              //for each element in all sets
    if(it.second > frequency) {
        mostFrequent = it.first;
        frequency = it.second;
    }
}

cout<<"answer is "<<mostFrequent<<endl;
```

Your question is a bit wierd in the sense that a `set`, by definition, won't have repeated elements in it, so it doesn't make sense to emphasize that you **don't** want the element that occurs the "*maximum number of times*", since it comes directly from the definition of `set` that this element will be the same as the one that occurs in the *maximum number of sets*.

If you mean a `set` that allow repeating elements, you should use `vector` or `list`. In this case, the solution would be converting such structure to a `set`.

Comment: Yes, you're right I could have used list or vector But that's not what I intend to do.The question needs to be solved using sets only.

Comment: This is why I used only sets. I just mentioned vector and list as they seem to fit in your case.

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel You can also "accumulate" the result ( since std::accumulate can be used for everything )

```
using pint = std::pair<int, int>;
auto res = std::accumulate(count.begin(), count.end(), pint(0,0), 
    [](const auto& e1, const auto& e2) { return e1.second > e2.second ? e1 : (pint)e2; 
  }
);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/fha8v8